# How to apply texture on an object?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am following some tutorials to cast a texture on a cylender so it is expected to be like a blood vessel. However, selecting any of these texture such as noise or clouds, etc... there will be no change on the surface. Please help have a look. Thanks in advance.
[image: blood vessel]

Blender file:
[image]

Comment: Reading "following some tutorials" I am wondering, are they doing it there? And if so, what are you doing differently so it does not work on your model?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann sometimes can't be replicated.

Comment: But I'm very confident that they didn't choose a texture there to use it in the material shader. If so, I would really be interested in those tutorials and how they did it, because they are usually either used for brushes or displacement. So maybe they painted a texture and brought it in with an _Image Texture_ node, but you cannot simply select a texture there from the dropdown and see it appear on the surface of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some technical reasons that someone will explain, you can't use the textures that are available in the *Texture* panel for your material, they are for *Displace* modifier for example. If you want to use a procedural texture for your material, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in the *Shader Editor* and create a *Texture > Noise Texture* for example, and plug it into a *Converter > ColorRamp* that you plug into the *Base Color* of your *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 'Legacy' texture system has been legacy for quite a while, now. I imagine, eventually, it will be wired into the nodes framework. But at the moment it lives on in the *Displacement* modifier, [Sculpting and Painting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/brush/texture.html).

If you create an *Image Texture* for your material, you can Texture-Paint into the chosen image, using a legacy texture as a brush. Here, the luminance of the image is being used to select color from a *Color Ramp*:

[image]

You can view the effect in Material Preview, as you paint:

[image]